# Why use both <thead> and <th scope="col">

Tags: html, html-table

I'm currently reading *"HTML & CSS: Design and Build Web Sites"* by Jon Duckett and in chapter 6, which is about tables, there is an example as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tables</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Home starter hosting</th>
                    <th scope="col">Premium business hosting</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Disk space</th>
                    <td>250mb</td>
                    <td>1gb</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Bandwidth</th>
                    <td>5gb per month</td>
                    <td>50gb per month</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Email accounts</th>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Server</th>
                    <td>Shared</td>
                    <td>VPS</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Support</th>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Telephone and email</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Setup</th>
                    <td>Free</td>
                    <td>Free</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">FTP accounts</th>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="2">Sign up now and save 10%!</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) that `<thead>` element defines a set of rows defining the head of the columns of the table. And `scope="col"` on `<th>` element is used to indicate that it is a heading for a column. My question is, do we really need to use both or is using one of them sufficient? Can/does `<thead>` do anything that `scope="col"` can't/doesn't do or vice versa?

Comment: https://webaim.org/techniques/tables/data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An important aspect here is **accessibility**:  By using `th` elements both on top and to the left with according `scope` attributes (col/row), screenreaders "understand" (and read/output in some way) that there are two headers for each `td`- one on top and one to the left. The important thing for that is not the `thead` element (which some browsers even add automatically if it isn't included in the original code, but which couldn't possibly be added for a column), but the `th` elements, which indicate header cells.

Answer (score 1):

While the `<th>` element defines the first row of your table as the header (e.g. via giving it a different style), the three tags `<thead><tbody><tfoot>` define the structure of your table. One example case is that some browsers enable scrolling of the table body independently of the header and footer.

You don't have to use any of them, it always depends on how you want your table to look and be structured.